# how to rotate google map marker to road direction

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to rotate marker icon to road direction, as you can see in image it only just placed but its not rotated to road direction.. i've tried below code as far

```
double lat = 19.205681
double lon = 72.871742
loc.setLatitude(lat);
loc.setLongitude(lon);
Location newLoc = new Location("service Provider");
newLoc.setLongitude(lat);
newLoc.setLongitude(lon);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(data.getLat(),data.getLon()))
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_pandu_car))
    .anchor(0.5f,0.5f)
    .rotation(loc.bearingTo(newLoc))
    .flat(true));
```

Note: marker have individual location (ofcource) i dont want to show from-to location bearing ...only individual marker to face on road direction

Thanks you 
[image]

UPDATE:i wanna set my marker (car) like this Ola app

[image]

Comment: If you are retrieving from the api, the uploading end must provide bearing for the server to return it to you. This is because you don't want to set the bearing based on the current location but, based upon the actual bearing of the provided locaiton.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, first check that is newLoc has bearing or not?
just made some changes as following, you can try it:

```
   LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location1) {
                        if (location1 != null) {
                            if (currentPositionMarker != null) {
                                currentPositionMarker.remove();
                            }
                            double latitude = location1.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = location1.getLongitude();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
                            if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                                currentPositionMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.current_position))
                                        .rotation(location1.getBearing()).flat(true).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                                        .alpha((float) 0.91));

                            } else {
                                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, activity, status);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: No its not working :( markers are still vertical (not as per road orientation).. can you please share whole code? or you want my more code for referance

Comment: @BSavaliya  same code I am using direction is not changing.`float bearing = prevLoc.bearingTo(current_location);
            markerOptions.rotation(bearing)` doing this helped me

Answer (score 0):

Following code works perfectly fine.

```
    private double radiansToDegrees(double x) {
        return x * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    }


    double fLat = (Math.PI * past.getLatitude()) / 180.0f;
    double fLng = (Math.PI * past.getLongitude()) / 180.0f;
    double tLat = (Math.PI * next.getLatitude()) / 180.0f;
    double tLng = (Math.PI * next.getLongitude()) / 180.0f;

    double degree = radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(sin(tLng - fLng) * cos(tLat), cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(tLng - fLng)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        bearing = degree;
    } else {
        bearing = 360 + degree;
    }

    marker.rotation((float) bearing);
```